# How to download attachment as binary data under strict mode?

Tags: javascript, strict-mode, bloburls

I am using the following function for downloading an attachment file, as binary data, inside an Office 365 app:

```
var saveByteArray = function (data, name) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    var blob = new Blob(data, { type: "octet/stream" }),
    url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = name;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};
```

It works successfully in Chrome browser, but following error has occurred, when I open it through the Outlook desktop client:

> Error TypeError: Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in
>   strict mode

The error happens, when executing this line:

```
access a.style = "display: none";
```

Is there any alternative solution for this implementation ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`#setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute) instead:

```
a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
```

I also recommend to use it when setting the other attributes of the `a` element.

Comment: it doesn't works .javascript code  uses "use strict" mode.

'Error
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'setAttribte' '

Comment: I made a typo, please try again with `setAttribute`